# $X_n$ be a sequence of +ve $L^1$ r.v. converging a.s. to $X\in L^1$ and $E(X_n) \to E(X)$ . Then $E(X_nY)\to E(XY)$ for any bounded r.v. $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, measurable-functions

Let $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of positive random variables such that $E(|X_n|)<\infty,\forall n\ge 1$ and $X_n \to X$ almost surely, where $E(|X|)<\infty$. Also assume $\lim_{n \to \infty} E(X_n)=E(X)$.

Then how to show that for any bounded random variable $Y$,  $\lim_{n\to \infty} E(YX_n)=E(YX)$ ?

Comment: @i707107: sorry about that ... see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Y$ is bounded, $|YX_n|\le MX_n$ for some $M>0$ and $\mathsf{E}MX_n\to \mathsf{E}MX$. The result then follows from the [generalized dominated convergence theorem](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-generalized-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem).

Comment: I'm not quite so sure since we don't know $E(|X_n|)\to E(|X|)$ ...

Comment: you're wrongly using the theorem ... $g_n$ are need to be non-negative ... what is your $g_n$ exactly ?

Comment: @user521337 $X_n$ are positive, aren't they?

Comment: ah yes ... thanks